# Unable to Connect to Git Host After Babun Re-Install

Tags: git, shell, cygwin, babun

I had previously installed babun on my machines C drive, in the default location, %userprofile%.babun and my installation was working perfectly. Because of space I had to move babun to a different drive. I uninstalled babun on the C drive. When I did this, I was unable to delete the .babun\cygwin\bin ssh-agent file and some other .dll files. I ran a new installation of babun on another drive and now I am unable to connect to git from the shell. I get a "Host key verification failed" message when I try to access git.

Has anyone experienced something similar after changing the install location and are there any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the .ssh folder at .babun\cygwin\home\your-user-name

Paste the .ssh folder from C:\Users\your-user-name into .babun\cygwin\home\your-user-name

In the babun shell, run the following commands:

```
cd ~
chgrp -R Users .ssh/
chmod -R 700 .ssh/
chmod 600 .ssh/id_rsa
```

Remember to add your username and email to git config using:

```
git config --global user.name "your name"
git config --global user.emial "your@email.com"
```

Regarding the files left over from the previous installation, restart the machine and you should be able to delete them.